# Every time view is seen, the name keeps on adding to itself

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I know that this sounds a bit dumb, but how do you call a function only once. I have a tab bar at the bottom of my app, and every time that it is called, the name that I got from my firebase database, keeps on being added. For example, the name in firebase is Bob. The app for the first time will display Bob. Then you would click on the settings, and go back to the home view. Then the app will say BobBob, and over and over again. How do I make this stop.

Code:

```
    import SwiftUI
    import Firebase

    struct HomeView: View {
        
        @State var name = ""
        
        var body: some View {
            NavigationView {
                ZStack {
                    VStack{
                        Text("Welcome \(name)")
                            .font(.title)

                        Text("Upcoming Lessions/Reservations:")
                            .bold()
                            .padding()
                        
                        Divider()
                        
                    }
                    
                }
                
            }
            .navigationTitle("Home")
            .onAppear(perform: {
                downloadNameServerData()
            })
            
            
        }
        private func downloadNameServerData() {
            
            let db = Firestore.firestore()
            db.collection("users").addSnapshotListener {(snap, err) in
                if err != nil{
                    print("\(String(describing: err))")
                    return
                }
                for i in snap!.documentChanges {
                    _ = i.document.documentID
                    if let Name = i.document.get("Name") as? String {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            name.append(Name)
                            print("\(name)")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
        
    struct HomeView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            HomeView()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Simplest way: Insert the line `if !name.isEmpty { return }` right before `let db = ...`. Alternatively use a view model and load the name in `init`.

Comment: Yes, it'd be good to just run it once (and @vadian gave you a couple of solutions for that). Note also that `append` means that it's going to add on to whatever you have. So, if you wanted to run on each onAppear (if that data may change, for example), you could do `name = Name`

Comment: It works now thank you. i implemented both of your solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    import SwiftUI
    import Firebase

    struct HomeView: View {
        
        @State var name = ""
        
        var body: some View {
            NavigationView {
                ZStack {
                    VStack{
                        Text("Welcome \(name)")
                            .font(.title)

                        Text("Upcoming Lessions/Reservations:")
                            .bold()
                            .padding()
                        
                        Divider()
                        
                        
                        
                    }
                    
                }
                
            }
            .navigationTitle("Home")
            .onAppear(perform: {
                downloadNameServerData()
            })
            
            
        }
        private func downloadNameServerData() {
            
            if !name.isEmpty { return }
            let db = Firestore.firestore()
            db.collection("users").addSnapshotListener {(snap, err) in
                if err != nil{
                    print("\(String(describing: err))")
                    return
                }
                for i in snap!.documentChanges {
                    _ = i.document.documentID
                    if let Name = i.document.get("Name") as? String {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            name = Name
                            print("\(name)")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
        
    struct HomeView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            HomeView()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider only loading the name if you don't have one yet?

```
.onAppear(perform: {
    if (name == null) downloadNameServerData()
})
```